# Wordpress FrontEnd Media Upload

Tags: php, wordpress, media, frontend

I'm trying to use Media Library in frontend 
Here is the code I'm using to create wp-editor :

```
wp_enqueue_media();
wp_editor( '', 'custom_editor_id' );
\_WP_Editors::enqueue_scripts();
print_footer_scripts();
\_WP_Editors::editor_js();
```

But the problem is that when I click on button Add Media, I receive:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

I've done a lot of research today, and didn't found a solution. Could you show me the way to do that?

Best Regards,
Mateusz

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I tried your code on a custom single template of the Twentyfifteen theme and it worked, I was able to upload and insert an image. I put your code between `get_header();` and `get_footer();`.

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks! But when you click on image, then on Insert Into Post, it won't work, it won't do anything